# how to get ip address of remote linux system using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

how to get ip address of LAN system having linux operating system using c#.net(running on windows server)

Comment: How does the system relate to yours? Is it connecting to you, or are you connecting to it? Do you know a hostname that you would like to resolve with dns? This question does not make much sense?

Comment: We will need a much more concrete question in order to have any hope of answering you.

Comment: how to get hostname of LAN system having linux OS using c#.net running on windows OS

Comment: You can edit your question ;)

Comment: By the way guys, take it easy on the newbies; -3 votes is a little harsh isnt it? We don't want to scare people off. Looks like there could be a language barrier here...

Comment: @Raghu - we'd like to help, please make your question clearer. You don't need to keep asking the same question.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to find the IP address of a remote Linux system from a C# application on a Windows server, the short answer is... you can't.

Instead, the Linux system will need to tell the C# application its IP address in some way, or the C# application will need to have the IP address of the remote system stored in configuration. (See the `System.Configuration` namespace, in particular use of `app.config`.)

If what you want to do is find the IP address of a host with a particular name, see here for a sample application that uses the `System.Net` namespace and `Dns.GetHostByName()`.

Comment: mcgee thnx for ur reply
pls confirm me one thing is it possible to get the hostname of a remote linux system using c#.net