# How to get the IP address of Remote Computer

Tags: c#

Assume there are two systems; System1 and System2.

- System1 - Windows XP
- System2 - Linux.

I have installed a WPF application on System1. A user on System2 connects to System1 via a Remote Desktop Connection and launches the WPF application.

In the WPF application, I can get the local IP address and Windows Login Name for System1 using the following code.

```
private String GetIP()
{
    string strHostName = "";
    strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
    IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
    return addr[0].ToString();
}

String WinUserName_withNetwork = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
String WinUserNameOnly = System.Environment.UserName;
```

My problem is I want the IP address and user name of the user logging in from System2.

What do I need to do in order to get that IP address and user name?

Comment: See the above
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046934/how-to-get-ip-address-of-remote-linux-system-using-c-net

Comment: Wait, *Windows* login name on a Linux system? Would you mind explaining what you mean? (Do you mean user name?)

Comment: *"Will launch the WPF application through Remote Connection"*. What is "Remote connection" in this sentence, and how do you launch the application "through" it?

Comment: HI Patrick. As unable to install the WPF application in Linux system(System2). So I connected the System1 via Remote Connection and launch the application. But I got the System1 information only.

Comment: What is Remote Connection? Is it Remote Desktop Connection or VNC? If you launch the applicaiton on System1 via such a program, it is *running on System1* so there's no way to get the information from System2.

Comment: Yes. Its running on System1. Application can be launched on System2 via Remote Desktop Connection.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question you want to know the IP address of the System2 from the System1 computer and the name of the user logged thru the remote connection. Am I right?

Assuming that you can use environment variables to gather this information:

1. CLIENTNAME: contains the name of the computer connected thru remote desktop.
2. USERNAME: contains the name of the user logged in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yupp, this is correct. You might add that you can get the environment variable using [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx).

Comment: For more advanced terminal service queries, there's a library called [Cassia](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/). There's also a SO question about it; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067846/how-can-i-get-the-client-computer-name.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer following Code:**

```
IPHostEntry iPAddress = DNS.GetHostByName (HostName);
 IPAddress [] IPAdd = iPAddress.AddressList;

 for (int j = 0; j < IPAdd.Length; j++)
 {
  Console.WriteLine ("IP Address {0}: {1} ", j, IPAdd[j].ToString ());
 }
```

Can also refer [THIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/get_ip11152005064604AM/get_ip.aspx) doccument.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open a command prompt / shell and type IPCONFIG

Look for an IP4 address. Quite often you'll see it's "127.0.0.1". Type NSLOOKUP  to get the name of the computer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why would you launch another application (which might not be consistent between platforms) for fetching the *local* IP address of the computer when you can do it in code?

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming. ;-)